# micropython not running by itself

Tags: micropython, pi-pico-w

so i got the code to work up until power it by a wall outlet. the code runs to to get the wifi with out issue, but then does nothing else during the time it is to turn on. if i connect back to the computer and run the code from Thonny, it works fine no issues. but if a disconnect and plug back in the wifi connects runs, but nothing else. here is the code again.

```
from machine import Pin, PWM
import network, socket
import utime, time
from datetime import datetime,timedelta, date
from time import mktime, sleep

ssid = [wifi]
password =  [wifi password]
led_pins = [16, 17, 26, 27, 28]

WIFIWait = Pin(28,Pin.OUT)
WIFICon = Pin(1, Pin.OUT)


def connect():
    #Connect to WLAN
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.connect(ssid,password)
    while wlan.isconnected() == False:
        WIFIWait.value(1)
        sleep(0.5)
        WIFIWait.value(0)
        sleep(0.5)
        print('Waitng')
    print(wlan.ifconfig())
    for x in range(3):
        WIFICon.value(1)
        sleep(0.5)
        WIFICon.value(0)
        sleep(0.5)
        
        
def control_leds(pin):
    pwm = PWM(Pin(pin))
    frequency = 5000
    pwm.freq(frequency)
    duty_step = 115
    for duty_cycle in range(0, 65536, duty_step):
        pwm.duty_u16(duty_cycle)
        sleep(0.05)
    for duty_cycle in range(65536, 0, -duty_step):
        pwm.duty_u16(duty_cycle)
        sleep(0.005)
    pwm.deinit()

def main():
    connect()
    while True:
        timenow = time.localtime()
        dt = datetime(*timenow[:6])
        print(timenow)
        sunset = dt.replace(hour=18, minute=0, second=0)  # Example sunset time (adjust as needed)
        morning = date.today() + timedelta(days=1)
        print("morning: ", morning)
        endtime = datetime(morning.year,morning.month,morning.day,2,0,0,0)
        if dt > sunset and dt < endtime:
            print("During sunset")
            LightPost = Pin(1, Pin.OUT)
            sleep(1)
            LightPost.on()
            print(LightPost)
            for pin in led_pins:
                control_leds(pin)     
        else:
            print("After sunset")
            LightPost = Pin(1, Pin.OUT)
            sleep(1)
            LightPost.off()
            sleep(3600)  # Sleep for an hour until next check

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

i will note that when i select the pico in Thonny after the disconnect i see this message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 73, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 70, in main
KeyboardInterrupt:
```

line 73 = " main()" Line 70 = " sleep(3600)"